# sphinx: Including .eps images via raw:: latex

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, eps, docutils

I would like to add an eps image within sphinx, using the raw:: latex command. I imagine something like this:

```
.. raw:: latex

    \includegraphics[width = 100mm, height = 100mm]{example.eps}
```

Running the sphinx-build command works perfectly, but oddly everything within the ..raw:: latex block is ignored in the html file.
What did I miss?

Do I need to enable the raw command in a docutils.conf file? I couldn't find that file in /etc .

Comment: well, i need a html output, so i am using the "sphinx-build -b html" command and get an html documentation. I just would like to use latex as a workaround in the reStructuredText file to use .eps images. I am open for any ideas ;)

Comment: Sry, but i really need an vector image. png does not look well within the Gtk Webkit

Comment: You can convert it to svg, which is also vector.

Answer (score 1):

The "raw" directive will only work for the specified output format(s).
So `.. raw:: latex` is ignored when generating HTML.

You may indicate more than one output format like `.. raw:: latex html`, but this will not help: The content is written to the output document verbatim and LaTeX commands do not work in HTML.

If you want a vector image in HTML, convert it to SVG.